# Change elements of a form in php based on the selection from a drop-down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dropdown

I have pre-defined equipment lists to be used in a form, based on the department selection. When I selected a department, the equipment list needs to change accordingly. The script doesn't seem to be called at all.

In HTML:

```
<select name="department_id" onchange="updateEquipmentList()" >
    <option value="2">Department 2</option>
    <option value="3">Department 3</option>
    <option value="4">Department 4</option>
</select>
```

In Javascript:

```
<script>
    function updateEquipmentList()
    {
        var myDepartment = document.getElementById("department_id").value;
        switch(myDepartment){
            case 2:
                equipment_list = <?php echo $equipment_2; ?>
                break;
            case 3:
                equipment_list = <?php echo $equipment_3; ?>
                break;
            case 4:
                equipment_list = <?php echo $equipment_4; ?>
                break;
        }
        <?php $str_equipment_list = "<script>document.write(equipment_list);</script>"; ?>
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code

```
<?php
$equipment_2 = 'Hammer';
$equipment_3 = 'Tape';
$equipment_4 = 'Cutter';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<div >
    <select id="department_id" name="department" onchange="updateEquipmentList()" >
    <option value="2">Department 2</option>
    <option value="3">Department 3</option>
    <option value="4">Department 4</option>
</select>
</div>


<script>
    function updateEquipmentList()
    {
        var myDepartment = document.getElementById("department_id").value;
        var equipment_list = '';
        switch(myDepartment){
            case '2':
                equipment_list = '<?php echo $equipment_2; ?>';
                break;
            case '3':
                equipment_list = '<?php echo $equipment_3; ?>';
                break;
            case '4':
                equipment_list = '<?php echo $equipment_4; ?>';
                break;
            default:
                equipment_list = 'Nothing';

        }
        document.write(equipment_list);

    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```